# Python y Flask - pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError

Tags: python, flask, pymongo

Estoy creando un CRUD con MongoDB, Flask y PyMongo, y al iniciar la aplicación obtengo el siguiente error:

```
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request 
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONG_DBNAME'] = 'gallery'
app.config['MONGO_URI'] = 'mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0.pnfts.mongodb.net/gallery'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
pictures = mongo.db.pictures

@app.route('/')
def home():
    pictures_data = pictures.find()
    return render_template('index.html', data = pictures_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: si haces `print(pictures_data)` que obtienes?

Comment: Seria mucho mejor si el error completo lo pones como texto por favor. ;)